# CMD Not Running 2nd Command ( & ) till first program is exited

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to start two programs simultaniously via CMD.

I'm more used to linux, normally I would create  2 commands in a script and just use `&` or `;` - but it doesn't seem to be working

I've tried a bunch of variances and w/ & w/o "quotes".

[Read this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd/8055430), but I'm stuck, hoping a Windows CMD person can help me out.

Here is the commands I want to run via a cmd/shortcut.

Note: It works when I paste in CLI though which really baffles me and frustrates me lol.

Note2: When running in cmd format, if I exit xpadder, then Project64 Launches, seems cmd is waiting for XPadder to close before moving to 2nd CMD when running via a *.cmd file vs pasting in the CMD window.

```
Taskkill /IM Xpadder.exe /F & "G:\Xpadder\Xpadder.exe" "G:\Xpadder\N64.xpadderprofile" & "G:\Emulators\N64\Project64\Project64.exe" "G:\Emulators\N64\Roms\Goldeneye 007.v64"
```

**Kill xpadder if running:**

```
Taskkill /IM Xpadder.exe /F
```

**Start XPadder w/ Specific Profile:**

```
"G:\Xpadder\Xpadder.exe" "G:\Xpadder\N64.xpadderprofile"
```

**Start Project64 w/ ROM:**

```
"G:\Emulators\N64\Project64\Project64.exe" "G:\Emulators\N64\Roms\Goldeneye 007.v64"
```

Comment: `&` in CMD means the same as `;` in (usual) Unix shells: do the left command and when that finishes (successful or not) do the right command; OTOH `;` is not special in CMD and is just a data character -- except in PATH and similar list-of-dirs Windows uses `;` as separator because `:` is contained in (nearly all) directory names, while Unix uses `:` as PATH separator.

Comment: I think the issue is i have a habit of stringing together commands in bash and it always works but seems It's better to put them on separate lines in Windows CMD. Im also just trying get in that habit for readability.

Answer (score 1):

After Reading this thread, I was able to get it to work via start.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487766/how-to-start-2-programs-simultaniously-in-windows-command-prompt

```
@ECHO OFF

Taskkill /IM Xpadder.exe /F
start /d "G:\Xpadder" Xpadder.exe "G:\Xpadder\N64.xpadderprofile"
start /d "G:\Emulators\N64\Project64" Project64.exe  "G:\Emulators\N64\Roms\Goldeneye 007.v64"
```